# Issue while using the jQuery function .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having an issue on my site where I am attempting to load the contents of a PHP file into a `<div>`.  I have ruled out the possibility that it is a server-side issue, so this leads me to my question.  Can you find anything wrong with the following code?

```
<script>
$('.navigation .responsive .menu ul li a').click(function()
{
    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href');
    $(".content").load(window.location.host + "/index.php?url=" + toLoad);
});
</script>
```

I am aware that for security reasons, browsers do not allow `.load()` to load content from external domains; however, would using `window.location.host` be an issue as it is the same domain?

Comment: what happens? Does it give you an error? Is it just blank? Did you try removing the `window.location.host`? You don't really need it.

Comment: Shouldn't all of that code be in a document.ready function?

Comment: @Connor: Not if it's after the elements in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.location.host` only includes the host name, not the protocol, which is necessary. Include that too:

```
$(".content").load(window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + "/index.php?url=" + toLoad);
```

Of course, you probably don't even need that; a leading `/` will get you an absolute URL:

```
$(".content").load("/index.php?url=" + toLoad);
```

Comment: You can also use `window.location.origin`, but only on WebKit-based browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `window.location.hostname` as `window.location.host` also includes port number and sometimes other characters